# googleplayにリリースしたアプリが音が出ない。

Tags: android, javascript, monaca, jquery

お世話になっております。

monacaでアプリ開発をしてるのですが、
googleplayでリリースしたアプリで音がでませんでした。
原因等わかればご教示ください。

■開発環境
monaca（Cordvaバージョン3.5.1）

・monaca DebuuggerでXPERIA端末からテスト⇒音がなる。
・デバッグビルドを行い、XPERIA端末から確認⇒音がなる。
・googleストアにリリースしアプリをインストールして確認⇒音がならない。

■ソースコード
スタートボタンを押したら音がなるようにしています。
必要部分を抜粋しているつもりですが、その他必要な情報等ございましたら
ご教示ください。

```
function start(){
    document.getElementById("Sound").play();
            }


<audio id="Sound" loop>
<source src="Sound3.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<div id="bottombar">
    <img id="button" src="start.png" onclick="start()">
</div>
```

Comment: sourceタグのとじ忘れではありませんか？

Comment: sourceタグに閉じは要りません。……ひとつ疑問なのですがMediaプラグインは設定済みでしょうか？（デバッグアプリで動いているので大丈夫かとは思いますが…)

Answer (score 1):

不思議な現象ですが、ハイパフォーマンス版 (Crosswalk版) でビルドするなどしてみるとどうでしょうか。自分のケースで恐縮なのですが、ビルドするとタグで音がならなかったことがあったのですが、ハイパフォーマンス版でビルドすると直りました。